# Rename a key value that is part of the React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a form with `key` and `value` input fields. I want the user to be able to edit key value pairs. Value simply edits the value, but key needs to update the key to what ever he is typing. I got the value change working, but I am not sure how to edit the key as this needs to update, remove and keep track of the key changed.

So lets say this is the current state:

```
{"name":"Joe"}
```

Now the user wants to edit name to firstname in the textfield.

As he types state will look like this with each keypress:

```
{"f":"Joe"}
{"fi":"Joe"}
{"fir":"Joe"}
{"firs":"Joe"}
{"first":"Joe"}
{"firstn":"Joe"}
etc
```

Here is my code:

```
function KeyValuePair({ initialPair }) {
  const [pairs, setPairs] = React.useState(initialPair ? initialPair : {});
  const handleInputUpdate = e => {
    const { name, value, id } = e.target;
    if (name === "key") {
      // ??
    }
    if (name === "value") {
      setPairs({ ...pairs, [id]: value });
    }
  };
}

<Grid item lg={3}>
  <TextField
    name="key"
    label="Key"
    id={key}
    value={key}
    margin="normal"
    onChange={handleInputUpdate}
    fullWidth
  />
</Grid>
<Grid item lg={3}>
  <TextField
    name="value"
    label="Value"
    margin="normal"
    id={key}
    value={pairs[key]}
    onChange={handleInputUpdate}
    fullWidth
  />
</Grid>
```

**UPDATE**

I have got it working like this:

```
const handleInputUpdate = e => {
  const { name, value, id } = e.target;
  if (name === "key") {
    const keyValue = pairs[id];
    let oldState = pairs;
    delete oldState[id];
    setPairs({ ...oldState, [value]: keyValue });
  }
  if (name === "value") {
    setPairs({ ...pairs, [id]: value });
  }
};
```

But this loses focus when typing because the old element is removed and new key rendered. Need to keep focus so you can keep typing.

Comment: Why not represent the key value pair as an object with a key property and a value property? Then the object definition doesn't change, just the values.

Comment: @HereticMonkey is right. This will make your code much easier to maintain and you will be less prone to React side-effects.

Comment: Yea, you guys were right, much better as suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your key is editable, you'll need to rely on another property that you can rely on whilst your key value pairs change - like a separate id, or their index position in an array.

Going down the array route, your entries would look something like this:

```
const initialEntries = [
  { key: "myKey", value: "myValue" },
  { key: "myOtherKey", value: "myOtherValue" },
  { key: "otherOtherKey", value: "otherOtherValue" }
];
```

If you map over your entries you can use the index:

```
 {entries.map((entry, index) => (
    <div>
      <span>{index}</span>
      <input
        name="key"
        onChange={ev => updateKey(index, ev)}
        value={entry.key}
      />
      <input
        nanme="value"
        onChange={ev => updateValue(index, ev)}
        value={entry.value}
      />
    </div>
  ))}
```

And then handle the updates:

```
 const updateKey = (id, ev) => {
    const newKeyValue = ev.target.value;
    const updatedEntries = entries.map((entry, index) =>
      index === id ? { ...entry, key: newKeyValue } : entry
    );
    setEntries(updatedEntries);
  };
  const updateValue = (id, ev) => {
    const newValueValue = ev.target.value;
    const updatedEntries = entries.map((entry, index) =>
      index === id ? { ...entry, value: newValueValue } : entry
    );
    setEntries(updatedEntries);
  };
```

Here's a working codesandbox that shows roughly how you can do it: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-cherry-n0518

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to steer away from an array route, but I guess this is the best way.